# how to get second highest salary department wise without using analytical functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Suppose we have 3 employees in each department.we have total 3 departments . Below is the sample source table

```
Emp deptno salary
A    10     1000
B    10     2000
C    10     3000
D    20     7000
E    20     9000
F    20     8000
G    30     17000
H    30     15000
I    30     30000
```

Output

```
B    10     2000
F    20     8000
G    30     17000
```

With using analytic function dense_rank we can achive the second highest salary dept wise.

Can we achieve this without using ANY analytic function ???

Is Max() is also analytic function ??

Comment: What rdbms are you using? Why can't you use an analytic function? `MAX` is an aggregate function

Comment: The answer is yes, it can be done. But why?

Comment: This was the question I got in an interview... This was the requirement... If can be done how can it be done ?? When I searched Google I got min and max also as analytic function in Oracle... Even count too .. so was struck there ...

Comment: i would ask, why would you make the code harder to write, read, and support? but then I probably wouldn't get the job

Answer (score 9):

It is a pain, but you can do it.  The following query gets the second highest salary:

```
select t.deptno, max(t.salary) as maxs
from table t
where t.salary < (select max(salary)
                  from table t2
                  where t2.deptno = t.deptno
                 )
group by t.deptno;
```

You can then use this to get the employee:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select t.deptno, max(t.salary) as maxs
      from table t
      where t.salary < (select max(salary)
                        from table t2
                        where t2.deptno = t.deptno
                       )
      group by t.deptno
     ) tt
     on t.deptno = tt.deptno and t.salary = tt.maxs;
```

Answer (score 5):

**Create table and insert dummy data**

```
CREATE TABLE #Employee
(
 Id Int,
 Name NVARCHAR(10), 
 Sal int, 
 deptId int
)


INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES
(1, 'Ashish',1000,1),
(2,'Gayle',3000,1),
(3, 'Salman',2000,2),
(4,'Prem',44000,2)
```

**Query to get result**

```
 ;WITH cteRowNum AS (
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY deptId ORDER BY Sal DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM #Employee
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM cteRowNum
 WHERE RowNum = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

This will give you 2nd highest salary in each department:

```
SELECT a.Emp, a.deptno, a.salary
FROM Emp a
WHERE 1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) 
        FROM Emp b 
        WHERE b.salary > a.salary AND a.deptno = b.deptno)
group by a.deptno
```

Comment: query is fine. But you can not use sub query table alias outside of query.(it will prompt with error: Unknown column 'd.deptno' in 'group statement')

Comment: This query will not even compile. GROUP BY clause is not balanced with SELECT clause.

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `Correlated Subquery`:

```
SELECT * FROM emp e1 WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sal)
                                  FROM emp e2 
                                 WHERE e1.sal <= e2.sal
                                   AND e1.deptno = e2.deptno
                               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite straightforward and declarative, but slow

```
select 
  t1.*
from 
  #tmp t1
  inner join #tmp h1 on h1.dept = t1.dept and h1.emp <> t1.emp
  left outer join #tmp h2 on h2.dept = h1.dept and h2.salary > h1.salary
  left outer join #tmp t2 on t1.dept = t2.dept and t2.salary > t1.salary and t2.emp <> h1.emp
where 
  t2.emp is null and h2.emp is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find 2nd highest salary something like this:

```
select max(a.Salary),a.Deptno from Employee a join (select MAX(salary) salary 
from Employee group by Deptno) b on a.Salary < b.salary group by a.Deptno
```

And no MAX() is not an analytic function.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Could you please add the analogy or description here in your solution, how it will work.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL this how you can get second highest salary, given table name is salaries:

By Nested Queries: (where you can change offset 0/1/2 for first, second and third place respectively)

```
select
  *
from
  salaries as t1 
where 
  t1.salary = (select 
               salary
             from 
               salaries
             where 
             salaries.deptno = t1.deptno ORDER by salary desc limit 1 offset 1);
```

or might be by creating rank: (where you can change rank= 1/2/3 for first, second and third place respectively)

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
select * from 
(SELECT
  s.*, 
  CASE 
      WHEN @prev_value = deptno THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
      WHEN @prev_value := deptno THEN @rank_count := 1 
      ELSE @rank_count := 1 
  END as rank
FROM salaries s
ORDER BY deptno, salary desc) as t
having t.rank = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
select 101 as id,   'Riya' as Name, 'HR' as Dept,   10000 as Salary UNION ALL
select 102, 'Kartik',   'IT',   25000 UNION ALL
select 103  ,'Yash' ,'Admin'    ,20000 UNION ALL
select 104, 'Pooja',    'IT',   35000 UNION ALL
select 105, 'Ankit',    'HR'    ,18000
),sec as 
(
select max(a.Salary) sal,a.Dept from data a   join (select Dept, MAX(Salary) salary 
from data group by Dept) b on a.Dept=b.Dept and  a.Salary < b.salary group by a.Dept
)
select * from sec UNION ALL
select Salary,Dept from data where Dept not in (select Dept from sec)
```

Answer (score -1):

**SQL Query:**

```
select TOP 2 max(salary),Emp from EMployee where deptno='your_detpno'
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: @mahesh you don't understand the question

Answer (score -1):

Very simple logic.

Please try:

```
SELECT dept as dd, ( SELECT ee.salary FROM `employees` as ee WHERE ee.dept=dd 
ORDER BY ee.salary DESC LIMIT 1,1 ) as sndHigh 
FROM `employees` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY dept
```

Comment: Oracle dosn't have `LIMIT`.

Answer (score -1):

```
select min(salary),deptno from
(SELECT distinct top 2 salary,deptno from table ORDER BY salary DESC)
as  a 
group by deptno
```

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
    ([Name] varchar(1), [Dept] varchar(1), [Salary] int)
;

INSERT INTO Employee
    ([Name], [Dept], [Salary])
VALUES
    ('a', 'M', 20),
    ('b', 'M', 25),
    ('c', 'M', 30),
    ('d', 'C', 44),
    ('e', 'C', 45),
    ('f', 'C', 46),
    ('g', 'H', 20)
```

Comment: And how does this answers to the question?

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Is this answer ti the question?