# Find second highest salary in each department using rank/dense_rank in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, rank, dense-rank

These were the two questions asked to me during an interview but only condition is to use rank/dense_rank.

> Find second highest salary in each department using rank/dense_rank in
>   hive.
>
> 1. When there are sufficient records in each department.
> 2. When there is only 1 record in few departments.

Guide me if this is even valid or not.
If yes then what should be the queries for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get second highest salary department wise without using analytical functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243365/how-to-get-second-highest-salary-department-wise-without-using-analytical-functi)

Comment: The question is by using analytical functions (rank/dense_rank) so it's a bit different from without using analytical functions (how to get second highest salary department wise without using analytical functions?)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to select all second salary employees then use

`dense_rank() over(partition by department order by salary desc) = 2` filter. It will return all employees with second salary.

When there is only 1 record in the department (no second salary exists, one employee in the department), it will be ranked 1 and you will get no records for that department filtering by dense_rank = 2.

If you need to select only one record (not all employees) with second salary then `row_number() over(partition by department order by salary desc) = 2` will work, but it will pick one random employee with second salary if there are many employees with second salary. Only one record will be marked with row_number = 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
WITH RESULT AS
(
SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department ORDER BY salary DESC) AS SecondHighest FROM Employee
)
SELECT IFNULL(( SELECT salary FROM RESULT WHERE SecondHighest = 2 ORDER BY salary) , NULL) as SecondHighestSalary
```